# what's crossdomain.xml?

Tags: php, cakephp, logging, crossdomain.xml

I have recently ran my website with `CakePHP`.
Today, when I was looking at the logs, I found this line:

```
Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class Crossdomain.xmlController could not be found.
```

It means this page is not found:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/crossdomain.xml
```

What's that XML file? and its usage?
I don't have link to this file in my website, so users shouldn't go to this page.. (also, I don't have any SWF media on my pages)

**Note**: I ran my website on a subdomain.

Thanks.

Comment: What was unclear in the first few Google search results?

Comment: [Read](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html)

Comment: @Wooble: they were about Flash media, which I don't have!...

Comment: Well, then someone's trying to fetch your crossdomain.xml for for no reason at all.

Comment: @Wooble: so what should I do? just ignore these errors?

Comment: If you don't want to make things on your site available to external flash applications, yes, you can ignore them. Along with the tons of requests you'll get looking for dozens of different CMSes with security holes, etc.

Comment: Yep they are just bots trying to find vulnerabilities into your site. Ignore them or you can block the IP address the request came from if it continues to happen from the same IP over and over.